# How to calculate "mean instant power"?

Tags: power, math

I have an homework assignement that gives me an headache, I have a circuit with a `2000W` heater with a all or nothing regulation using a thermostat

The heater is running 1/2 hour then stop for 1h from 6pm to 6am next day, so I calculated the duty cycle ratio (`Time powered`/`(Time [s] powered + Time not powered)` <=> (8*30)/((8*30)+(9*60)) which is 0.31.

I need to calculate the `mean instant power` of that circuit, I went to the conclusion that this value would be `nominal power` * `duty cycle ratio` but I'm not sure at all of that

Am I right with my calculation?

Comment: Could you show us your work for how you got 0.31? Also, how you calculated the "6h straight"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Mean instant" is an [oxymoron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxymoron).**

It is 2kW at the instant it is ON and 0 at the instant it is OFF.

But 0.5 h ON and 1 h OFF in a 1.5h cycle for any duration is 1/3 duty cycle **so your mean power is 2/3 kW.**

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete answer because the question needs a bit of a clean-up.

> The heater is running 1/2 hour then stop for 1h ...

That's a 1.5 hour duty-cycle

> ... for 6h straight (from 6pm to 6am next day)

6 p.m. to 6 a.m. is not 6 h. You need to fix that.

> I need to calculate the mean instant power of that circuit,

Instant power is the power at any single time. This will be 2000 W or zero.

The mean power is the time averaged power.

> I went to the conclusion that this value would be nominal power * duty cycle ratio but I'm not sure at all of that.

That's mean power, not "mean instant power".

Fix the 6 h straight bit and we'll try to answer.

Comment: I have edited what I could, and it is written `mean instant power` in the assignement (I know it's quite dumb (feel like it's an error))